# Function ip2long fails in class

Tags: php, class, ip2long

When I use the ip2long function in a class, it does not return a valid result. If I call the function outside of the class, as shown, it returns a valid result. But if I use the class, the conversion is ignored. So I assume the problem is with the class but don't know what that is. Would someone please point out my mistake, please?

```
    echo  ip2long('1.0.1.10');  //gives 16777482

    $ip_checker = new ip_checker;
    echo $ip_checker->CheckIP('1.0.1.10'); //gives 1.0.1.10

    class ip_checker {
      public function __construct() {
      }

      public function CheckIP($ip) { 
        $ip = ip2long($ip);
        return $ip;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/EAjnB

Comment: That is most curious... sadly, I was unable to get this to behave as you are showing. I get `16777482` `16777482`

Comment: You need to check the code and post what will reproduce the issue.

Comment: I don't think it's possible from this code alone. There must be something else affecting it.

Comment: I created a stand-alone script and it worked. I then removed all of my changes to the site and copied that code into it and it worked too. So this is a non-issue. My thanks to all who replied and I apologize for the bother.